# Inverse indicator function set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this True\False question:
if A,B are subsets of a universal set U, then $\chi^{-1}_A( \{1\})\cap\chi^{-1}_B( \{0\})=A\setminus B$

I feel like this is False because it intersects a group with elements that are not in A with elements that are in B, which is $B\setminus A$ .

That being said, I am still unsure about the definition of the indicator set, and how it's being used here.

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: $\chi_A^{-1}(1)$ is $A$.  $\chi_B^{-1}(0)$ is $B^c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the definition of the indicator set function:
$$\chi_A (x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if } x\in A\\
0 \quad \text{if } x\not\in A\\
\end{cases}$$
It practically tells you whether an element is on the set or not.

Therefore, $\chi_A^{-1}(\lbrace 1\rbrace) = \lbrace x\in U: \chi_A(x)=1\rbrace = A$. So the condition translates, directly from definition, into $A\cap B^c = A$\ $B$.